# Regular expression 10 digit phone number capture

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am trying to match 10 digit phone numbers (that start with 2-9) that are on word boundaries (i.e. there is white space around them.) Sometimes the above phone numbers are prefixed with an +1 or 1

I would like it to still match the 10 digit phone number that follows but discard the +1 or 1  There can be multiple phone numbers in the text.
Here is my regexp

```
\b(([+]?[1-9]{1})?([2-9][0-9]{9}))\b

https://regex101.com/r/yS1vM4/1
```

Shows matches. However it doesn't match for the first row of numbers and it should NOT match on the 2nd and last row:

```
abcd +12125551212 xyz should match starting at 212 
abcd +2125551212 xyz should NOT match (+ sign only)
abcd 2125551212 xyz  match OK!
abcd+12125551212 xyz should NOT match (no white space at start)
abcd 12125551212 xyz should match starting at 212
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better one.

```
(?<!\S)(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d{9})(?!\S)
```

Formatted ([this](http://www.regexformat.com)):

```
 (?<! \S )            # Look behind, whitespace or ^ 
 (?: \+? 1 )?         # Optional +1
 ( [2-9] \d{9} )      # (1), ten digit phone
 (?! \S )             # Look ahead, whitespace or $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use this regex for your examples:

```
/(?:(?<= [+][1-9])|(?<= [1-9])|(?<= ))([2-9][0-9]{9})\b/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS1vM4/2)

Or else this this regex and use matched group #1:

```
/\s([+]?[1-9])?([2-9][0-9]{9})\b/gi
```

[RegEx Demo 2](http://%5Cs(?:[%20]?[1-9])?([2-9][0-9]%7B9%7D)%5Cb)

Comment: I like the first one, works in the cases I provided. But will not work for a number that is at start of line . I added a \b in front hoping it would work. Any improvement that can be done? -thanks

Comment: If you also want to match numbers at start then why did you add **(no white space at start)**?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I meant no white space at start of number.

Comment: Ok, I added an alternate (?<=\b) and it works -thanks